# How to reduce space between two subfigures

Tags: spacing, subfloats, vertical-spacing, setspace

I'm using this code for creating my figures:

```
\begin{figure}[h!t!b] %-Figure
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:a}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:b}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:3}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:4}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:5}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
         \centering
         \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/white.jpg}}
         \raisebox{2\abovecaptionskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
          \caption{}
          \label{fig:6}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Six simple images}
    \label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
```

then I got the following result:

[image]

My question is - how can I control the thickness of the vertical and horizontal space for this case? or at least, how can I equalize the thickness of the horizontal space to the thickness of the vertical space..

Thanks!

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Did you try making `0.49\textwidth` smaller?

Comment: BTW, (almost) every time you end a line with } you are adding a space.  After two subfigures this is good, since it allows a line break.  \allowbreak would be better, but leaving a blank line between rows is more common.

Comment: Normally there is only `\lineskip` between rows, But while `\raisebox` here has no height, it does have width and takes up a line of (blank) text (`\baselineskip`).  The question is whther you want to remove it (I generally add `\floatsep` between rows).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Changing `0.49\textwidth` is not a solution because I want to reduce the horizontal space, not adding a vertical space..
@JohnKormylo I don't really understand your answer (I'm a beginner..). How can I define the `\floatsep` locally, only for this figure and where exactly in the code I need to do that? Thanks!

Comment: \floatsep is predefined as the space between two (top) floats.  Similarly, \textfloatsep is the space beteen a top or bottom float and the text, and \intextsep is the space above and below an [h] float.